# xml validation tool like api

Tags: c#, python-3.x, xml

I have my xml files like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BlTextMain xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    ..........................
    <Consignee>FREIGHTPLUS (THAILAND) CO., LTD.</Consignee>
    <ConsigneeAddress1>FREE TRADE FACILITY</ConsigneeAddress1>
    <ConsigneeAddress2>919/229 MOO 12, T.THUNGSUKLA, A.SRIRACHA, </ConsigneeAddress2>
    **<ConsigneeAddress3>CHONBURI 20230, THAILAND.&#xB;</ConsigneeAddress3>**
    <ConsigneeAddress4>TEL: +66(0)33 048 387</ConsigneeAddress4>
    <ConsigneeCountry>TBA</ConsigneeCountry>
    .....
</BlTextMain>
```

In ConsigneeAddress3 node value: CHONBURI 20230, THAILAND.***&#xB***;
there is a hexadecimal character present.So this is not a perfect xml.
Online editor like https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xml-validator works perfectly.
But I want to write my own api for my project.Could someone help me to write in C#/Java/Python.
I have tried C# XmlDocument.Validate() but its does not work for hexadecimal or extended hexadecimal characters.

Comment: 0x0b is indeed invalid in XML version 1.0 (which XML in the post uses)... So could you please [edit] post to clarify what "validation" you want to perform (not that .Net *does not* support XML version 1.1 which would allow that character)?

Comment: I am using xml version 1.0

Comment: Please [edit] post with that information and really there is no need for such huge example... Some couple small 3 lines complete examples should be enough to clarify what you personally would like to consider "valid" and "invalid" XML-like file. After you do so recommendations would likely be along the lines "use more lax parser like HtmlAgilityPack" and than validate tree to your liking"... Alternatively reconsider what you consider "valid" and stick with XML 1.0 specification - would make working with others much easier as you'd not need to explain your validity rules every time.

Comment: I have edited plz send me some details of the code.@AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: I tried my best to convince you to use XML... and failed. I'm not interested in discussing/helping to write parser for XML-like text files... I hope guidance I gave above to use HtmlAgilityPack could help... but again - this is not something I'd ever recommend doing as it put burden on other people who may endup interacting with code that you will create and had to deal with XML-like text instead of XML which is pain. Good luck - text parsing is good skill to have so you may even consider writing validator from scratch to validate whatever rules you like.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have XML files, but you are wrong. You have non-XML files.

So the question is what to do about it.

If you can change your workflow to use XML, instead of something that is almost-like-XML-but-not-quite, then you will be able to use standard off-the-shelf XML tools (many of which are free and/or open-source) and you will save yourself a lot of money. If your workflow uses non-standard formats, however close they might be to a standard, you are making a lot of extra effort for yourself and adding a lot of cost.

So the firm recommendation is: find out who is generating this bad data and get them to change their ways.

If you can't do that, then you will need to incur the expense of repairing the data; and the key thing to bear in mind is that because it is non-XML data, it can only be repaired using non-XML tools.